# haskell: change lowercases to capitals in a list of strings

Tags: string, list, haskell

My problem is, I would like to change every lowercase letter of the list `["hello","wHatS", "up?"]` into capitals.

`map toUpper [x]` does not work realy...

it should return ["HELLO", "WHATS", "UP?"]..

Comment: `toUpper` is `Char -> Char`, you have `[[Char]]`, you need to map twice.

Comment: map map toUpper [list] ?

Comment: Almost ;) `map (map toUpper) yourList`.

Comment: arggghh those brackets hahaha, thank you

Comment: someone (@Mark ?) should make this into an answer so we can close the question ;)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at type of `toUpper`, it's `Char -> Char`, but you have `[[Char]]`. It means that you have two layers of list functor here, so you should map it twice.

For pedagogical reasons we may use `map` here, like this:

```
map (map toUpper) yourList
```

Parenthesis are important here, we give one argument to `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` and get another function of type `[Char] -> [Char]` (just what we need!) because of curring.

Once you learn about functors, you may prefer `fmap` and `<$>` for this task:

```
(toUpper <$>) <$> yourList
```

Comment: btw: I don't think the doulbe `<$>` is preferable - although `map toUpper <$> yourList` might be an option, if readability is concernced ;)

Comment: `fmap`then. I don't think `map` is used in modern Haskell. It seems like haskellers prefer powerful abstractions, like functor, monads, traversable, foldable, etc. `fmap` is more abstract since we can map any functor with it, not just lists.

Comment: I think in this case the abstraction is not really needed - if you start talking to a beginner like this Haskell will be a dead language soon ;)